# How to format all cells in one sheet based on corresponding cell values in another sheet using XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am exporting to Excel two pandas `DataFrames` using XlsxWriter, each `DataFrame` having a separate sheet. I would like to apply a colour format to all the cells in one sheet based on values in another sheet, they correspond one-to-one based on column names and row numbers.

Example:

```
Sheet1

  A B C
1 1 3 1
2 0 4 2

Sheet2

  A B C
1 a d b
2 b a a
```

I would like to assign a colour format to all the cells in Sheet1 that have a value 'a' in Sheet2.

Comment: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: would you consider using `openpyxl` instead of `XlsxWriter`?

Comment: Yes, I am not tight to using XlsxWriter.

Comment: If possible I would like to keep the separate sheets, and I did not find an example like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is to work out the conditional format in Excel and then transfer it to XlsxWriter.

Something like the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[ 1,   3,   1 ], [ 0,   4,   2 ]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'd', 'b'], ['b', 'a', 'a']])

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_xlsxwriter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=False, index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', header=False, index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Create a format for the conditional format.
condition_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                                        'font_color': '#006100'})

# Write a conditional format over a range.
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:C2', {'type': 'formula',
                                       'criteria': '=Sheet2!A1="a"', 
                                       'format': condition_format})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Note that Excel requires double quotes around the string in the formula `=Sheet2!A1="a"` and by using a [relative cell reference](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#relative-and-absolute-cell-references) (`A1` not the absolute value `$A$1`) the formula is applied individually to each cell in the range.

You can apply the conditional format to a range based on the dataframe like this:

```
# Write a conditional format over a range.
start_row = 0
start_col = 0
end_row = df1.shape[0] -1
end_col = df1.shape[1] -1

worksheet.conditional_format(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col, 
                             {'type': 'formula',
                              'criteria': '=Sheet2!A1="a"', 
                              'format': condition_format})
```

Comment: Yes, I am using XlsxWriter to export my DataFrames to Excel. Part of the question, is it possible to specify it for all the cells in the sheet, or I have to assume some range always?

Comment: You can specify a range that covers the entire worksheet. I.e., `A1:XFD1048576` or `(0, 0, 1048575, 16383)`.

Comment: I like the idea of setting the range to the DataFrame actual size better!